# Applying a general LessThan or GreaterThan filter for all numeric types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have to write some code that using LINQ to filter some records, say some records that have a property LessThan (or GreaterThan) some filter value. The problem is that the records that come from database can have any numeric type fields, and all of them should be considered for filtering.

For example if the field is, say **int** , then my filter code looks something like

```
var filterValue = filter.Value; //Some Filter Value entered by user

var itemType = item.GetType().GetProperty(filter.Field).PropertyType; //Particular field type 
var itemValue = item.GetType().GetProperty(filter.Field).GetValue(item, null); //field value (comes from database)
```

In order to filter the records for say **int** I use code something like this

```
switch (filter.Operator) { //filter operator for LessThan is lt
    case "lt":
        try {
            if (itemType == typeof(int)) {
                return (int)itemValue < int.Parse(filterValue);
            }
            else if (...) //Test for all other numeric types in c#
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }
        break;
}
```

The above code handles the **int** type fields comming from the database. The **else if (...)** part is what I will have to write for all other numeric types. Any ideas, how I can write that part without hard coding the type checks for all the numeric types.

Comment: What's wrong with `Convert.ToInt32`? It can get object as argument and you don't have to worry about its actual type. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can't you use directly IComparable? All numeric types already implement it, so you can use directly its CompareTo method

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not much use `for all other numeric types`.

Comment: @Rawling (and Nirvan) maybe it's just me, but why this won't work? `return Convert.ToInt32(itemValue) < int.Parse(filterValue);`

Comment: If the `filterValue` is `"1.5"` and the `itemValue` is `(object)1.25` and the `itemType` is `float` or `double`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Rawling has correctly pointed the issue with your approach in his comment.

Comment: Oh my, that's right. OK, hope to think of something then! :)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella I tried to use IComparable, but as "filterValue" comes in as string, the following code throws exception: if (((IComparable)itemValue).CompareTo((IComparable)filterValue) < 0) {}